# jQuery: datepicker, auto click /pick a date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
          onSelect: function(dateText) {
            $.post('/admin/deals/booking/', 
            { date: dateText }, function(data) {

                if(data != '0')
                {
                    $('input[name=book_date]').val(dateText);
                    $('#results').html(data);
                    $('.current_text').html(dateText);
                    $('.book_deal').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
          }
        });

        $( "#button" ).bind('click', function(){
});
    });
    </script>
```

I want when pressing on #button it should activate the above #datepicker, like you have clicked on the date and selected date 2012-02-02

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate), datepicker provides is a `setDate` method:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '2012-02-02')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({---});`

write

`$( "#button" ).datepicker({---});`